# Cyberpunk novel by female author which took place on a boat

Tags: story-identification, novel, cyberpunk

I read this novel by a woman author in the 1990's. It had elements of cyberpunk/ genetic modification/ nanotech. My most vivid recollection is that at the end one of the characters was attacked by her disappointed parents with technology that turned her back into an infant. During much of it, the characters are fleeing or hiding out in a boat on a river.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember where the boat was?  The Mississippi for instance?

Comment: Nanotech + 1990s + boat + female author suggests Kathleen Ann Goonan to me, but I'm really not sure about the part about turning someone back into an infant.

Comment: Thanks, DavidW. Goonan's Mississippi Blues has the right setting and technology per online reviews, but I can't confirm it has the scene I remember.

Comment: *Mississippi Blues* really doesn't have a scene like that that I can recall, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Gaia's Toys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia%27s_Toys) by Rebecca Ore, published in 1995.

> In a dark American future of customized gene restructuring and computer-controlled lifestyles, a group of eco-terrorists band together to stop the creation of a new mutation that threatens the last scrap of human freedom.

[image: Gaia's Toys]

The character who is turned back into an infant by her parents is *Dorcas Rae*:

> Her mother said, “Dorcas, you’ve been a disappointment to us since you were in high school.”
>
> “Not that we didn’t spoil you,” her father said. “But our doctor thought you were our best genetic combination.”
>
> “Yes, Daddy, I’m your gourmet child.” The ice cube had melted unnaturally quickly.
>
> Her mother said, “Sit down, Dorcas. We feel we owe you an explanation for what we’ve done.”
>
> Dorcas felt her body shift. “It was in the drink? Nanotech? You’re changing me. Please change my retinas. Loba couldn’t risk it because I’m wanted everywhere.”
>
> “Yes,” her mother said. “We know how we’d raise you this time.”
>
> Paul said, “It’s not like we’re killing you. We’re just going to reduce you to babyhood.”

Comment: Yes, that is definitely it! Thanks for the ID!